# How can sync two jira instances using either Mule or Mule Studio?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I want to sync two jira instances using using either Mule ESB or Mule Studio (custom connector). Here Mule will act as middleware for two jira instances. If some activity is performed in JIRA-1 ex., issue is created it should be replicated in JIRA-2.

Is this possible using Mule ESB or Mule Studio ?

I am not getting starting point for this. Currently I am looking for Mule Orchestration for this.

Can someone guide me in right direction ?

```
<jira:config name="Jira_A" doc:name="Jira_for_A" >
</jira:config>

<jira:config name="Jira_B"  doc:name="Jira_for_B">

</jira:config>

<flow name="consuming-from-jiraA" doc:name="consuming-from-jiraA">
    <poll doc:name="Poll" frequency="1000">
        <jira:get-issues-from-jql-search connectionAddress="http://localhost:8080/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2" 
             connectionPassword="admin" connectionUser="admin"
            config-ref="Jira_A" jqlSearch="project = &quot;MULE ESB&quot; AND key = ME-1"
            maxNumResults="100" doc:name="Jira_for_A" />
    </poll>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <jira:create-issue config-ref="Jira_B" doc:name="Jira_for_B"
            project="WT" summary="Mule ESB :Jira sync test issue 1 " type="2" connectionAddress="http://192.xxx.x.xx:8091/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2" connectionPassword="admin" connectionUser="admin">
        </jira:create-issue>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

[image]

Comment: trying jira-connector with the JQL query syntax.using connector within poll and query one of your jiras instances to retrieve information and then hit the other jira instance to reflect it if it doesn't exists. but not able to orchestrate integration of application. Can someone please help me in resolving this.

Comment: what do you mean by orchestrate integration of application ?

Comment: arrange the flow. which components to use to communicate jira instances.I have update my question with what I am trying.

Comment: updated question. What I am trying to do is sync two jira instances running on two different servers. so that if issue is created/updated/deleted at JIRA-1 same is cloned/copied at JIRA-2. I am able to hit one jira I using jira connector for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782498/how-can-i-connect-mule-studio-to-jira-to-create-a-jira-issue But I am not able to integrate/sync two jira. Can some one help me resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the jira-connector with the JQL query syntax?

I have not tried before, but I assume you could use the jira connector within a poll, and query one of your jiras instances to retrieve information you want (ticket) and then hit the other jira instance to reflect it if it doesn't exists.

Try if it works.